# Cannot write to properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, properties-file

I have the following spring class, which tries to write a new property value in a properties file:

```
@Service
public class Operations {

    public void changeProperties() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream("rest-endpoint.properties");
            prop.setProperty("meta.db.device.url", "localhost");
            prop.store(output, null);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

I also tried this code:

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("Prop1", "toto");
    File f = new File("rest-endpoint.properties");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( f );
    DefaultPropertiesPersister p = new DefaultPropertiesPersister();
    p.store(props, out, "Header Comment");
} catch (Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and my `rest-endpoint.properties` file is:

```
meta.db.device.url=http://edgex-core-metadata:48081/api/v1/device
meta.db.devicemanager.url=http://edgex-core-metadata:48081/api/v1/devicemanager
meta.db.ping.url=http://edgex-core-metadata:48081/api/v1/ping
```

However, when I execute the code, nothing changes in the properties file. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Even though this is definitely possible I advise against it. The normal usage of properties files from an application is read-only. If you start writing to those files people will be confused. If you need to store dynamic state use the Preferences API or a database.

Comment: Maybe the file isn't written where you think it is, try to print the value of `f.getAbsolutePath()` .

Comment: @Arnaud are you talking about the second code snippet? Should I print this after I do `File f = new File()`?

Comment: @Marievi : yes try that.

Comment: @Arnaud the result is `/rest-endpoint.properties`.

Comment: I'd bet this does write to the properties file, but it writes to the properties file in `/target` not `/src` as you might be expecting.